# Unity, C# - cannot make object move down from current y position ONCE on collision enter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having a frustrating problem with animations. I have a spawning platform prefab that I have attached animations to, and I want to move the platform down from its ORIGINAL Y POSITION **once** when a player object lands on it, stay down as the player is sitting on it, then move back up to original position when the player exits collision (i.e jumps off).

I have created my up and down animations and set them both to playing ONCE using the Animation window. I then dragged the platform to my project to make it a prefab and plugged it back into my spawn script.

When the player collides (lands on the platform), I call the down animation here:

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col) {
        GameObject platform = col.gameObject;

        //platform.GetComponent<Animation> ().Play ("down1");
        if (!playedAnim1) {
            platform.GetComponent<Animation> ().Play ("down1");

            playedAnim1 = true;
        }
        touchingPlatform = true;
        Debug.Log ("entering platform");
    }

    void OnCollisionExit (Collision col) {
        playedAnim1 = false;
        GameObject platform = col.gameObject;
        //platform.SetActive (false);
        //platform.transform.position += new Vector3 (0f, -1f, 0f);
        //platform.GetComponent<Animation> ().Play ("up1");

        touchingPlatform = false;
        Debug.Log ("exiting platform");
    }
```

To make the animation only play once, I set a boolean flag called `playedAnim1`. I would think this would make the animation only play once but when the player lands on platform it plays over and over several times. It is as if when the player lands on the platform, the platform moves up instead of down despite the animation being correct.

I've tried just changing the `col.transform.position` directly but this doesn't work either. How can I have the platform move down and STAY THERE when the player lands on it, and back up when it leaves?

EDIT: I've connected transitions here, with Down->Idle down on parameter bool `isDown`to true, Idle down-> Up on bool isDown to false, Up -> Idle up parameter bool isUp to true, Idle up-> Down bool isUp to false.

[image]

Here is the code Ive implemented:

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col) {
        Debug.Log ("enter");
        col.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("isUp", false);
        animUpSwitch = false;
        if (!animDownSwitch) {
            animDownSwitch = true;
            col.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("isDown", true);
            col.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator> ().Play ("down");
        }

        touchingPlatform = true;
    }

    void OnCollisionExit (Collision col) {
        Debug.Log ("exit");
        animDownSwitch = false;
        col.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("isDown", false);

        if (!animUpSwitch) {
            animUpSwitch = true;
            col.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("isUp", true);
            col.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator> ().Play ("up");
        }

        touchingPlatform = false;
    }
```

And its still moving up and down uncontrollably

Answer (score 0):

I used to create four clips for this kind of situation

1. Move_Down
2. Idle_Down
3. Move_Up
4. Idle_Up

I tell animator to play Move_Down and after the clip is finished I have the clip transition to Idle_down so basically it will keep it down unless the clip is changed.
When User Jumps from platform I play Move_Up and the same as before transition to Idle_Up state in animator after end of earlier clip. Animator keeps on playing the same clip unless you tell it to stop or change through code. The idle clips are Extreme Y values.

I use the above steps because they are much easy to implement while you can make it work with just two clips but i prefer this method.

So the flow will be

> **anim.play("Move_Down") -> transition to "Idle_Down"**

which will make it go down and stay there
if you want to return it back

> **anim.play("Move_Up ") -> transition to "Idle_Up"**

Also you will have to take care of clip reanimating from middle of transition if player moves to next platform before reaching minY of platform.

> A major thing you have to note here is that if you are trying to
>   modify you position and rotation values of transform then those values
>   if they are in the clip then you should turn off the animator as
>   animator will ovveride the position/rotation values. Although you can
>   override the animator position/rotation values in LateUpdate().

Hope this bit of information is helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you. How can I transition to an animation? Is there a way to do it in code?

Comment: you will need to add the animation clips in Animator. After creating clips then you need to manage it. Are you by any chance never user Animator in unity? Then I would suggest you to look at the tutorials and see through it. It is really easy to implement. http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation 
The above page has all the necessary information.

Comment: Ok. I went through several tutorials there and on youtube with animation transitions and think I implemented them correctly but still can't get the desired effect. I've updated my question- really need some help. Finding it very difficult here

Comment: Can you help me out with the scripting on transitions?

Comment: come in this chat room we will discuss it over there http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115596/unitychat i will be waiiting